# Efficient way to calculate minutes between int time and midday

Tags: python, time

I have a panda data frame which contains a column of times in integer format hhmm (ie, 1200, 1415, 1859).

I want to calculate the total number of minutes each 'time' is from midday.

I thought of converting the int into a datetime series, creating a constant by converting '1200', subtracting the two, and converting back into minutes.   But it seems inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Thank you

Comment: You should probably store the times as real timestamps in the first place. What's the benefit of storing them as `int` in the first place?

Comment: That's just the format the data was provided in.

Comment: Convert it; an `int` isn't appropriate for the kind of timestamp. `2587`, for example, is a valid `int` but not a valid hour-minute timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
noon = int(1200 / 100) * 60 + (1200 % 100)
currentTime = int(INPUT / 100) * 60 + (INPUT % 100)

abs( currentTime - noon)
```

We first account for the minutes in each hour (checking the total number of hours by dividing 1200/100 and getting an integer representation), then we add on any leftover minutes (taking 1200 modulo 100).  The absolute value of the difference between this calculation for noon and the timestamp will give us the distance in minutes.

Comment: That worked - apart from I needed to remove the 'int' function from currentTime